# How to allow a word that contains a banned word?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating a filtering function for my form's username input to permit the use of specific banned words.

I am currently using:

```
var forbiddenWords = ["c*m", "blabla", "blablabla"];
// Check for forbidden words
function isForbiddenWord(value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < forbiddenWords.length; i++) {
        var rgx = new RegExp(forbiddenWords[i], 'gi');
        if (rgx.test(value)) {
            forbiddenWord = forbiddenWords[i];
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

The first word in the array, "c*m", is for obvious reasons a banned word. If for example somebody types in the username "eat_a_c*mshot" I want it banned. If somebody else types in: incumbent_king, encumbrance, accumulate_wealth, cumbersome, im_a_scum, circumvent, sweet_cucumber and so on, I want these words to be allowed.

Is there a way to identify if such words are used and permit them, like with a regular expression or so, or I am asking too much?

Comment: With just regular expressions? Not really. First you need to come up with a criteria for what is allowable. Natural language processing is a huge field.

Comment: You have discovered the *"Scunthorpe problem"*. You can't solve it with regex.

Comment: At it's core, there's no way to distinguish `cumbersome` from `c*mshot` in the detection regex. You will have to ban every specific variation of every banned word. Also, there will be people who substitute letters or omit vowels. It's quite an uphill battle.

Comment: Setting aside, for a moment, the difficulties in correctly identifying the set of usernames to block . . . you should probably be doing this on the server-side, not the client side. Otherwise any tech-savvy users can easily circumvent it.

Comment: @ruakh Javascript is also a server-side language

Comment: @ruakh any tech-savvy users that will manage to circumvent it will be banned a bit later. I do use some server-side filtering though as well.

Comment: @BrendanAbel: I'm aware of that, but "my form's username input" practically screams "client side". (And the OP has since confirmed that this is client-side.)

Comment: @4castle would it be possible to have c*m banned and make an array of words like cucumber, cumbersome and so on, like 20 of these and allow them? Like say do not ban cum if it is part of these words?

Comment: @AngelPolitis Yes you could do that, but at the end of the day, depending on the scale of your application, you might consider just flagging the account for human-review after it is created instead of "banning". Hopefully there are moderators?

Comment: @4castle how could I do that? I am out of ideas on how to code that. I have flagging in mind to implement it later as a more advanced feature.

Comment: I would add a hidden field to the form which just says `flagged=true` in the request. When your backend encounters it, have the username logged to a file or database for review.

Comment: No no, I mean to allow an array of words that include c*m but not anything else.

Comment: There's no way you can do this with complete accuracy. You'll always have some false positives, and you'll always let through some creative variations. 7h3r3 4r3 4ny numb3r 0f w4y5 7h47 4 u53r c0uld 5ub5717u73 07h3r ch4r4c73r5, br34k up w0rd5 w17h punc7u4710n, 5p3ll 7h3m b4ckw4rd5, bu7 571ll h4v3 7h3 b4nn3d w0rd5 b3 r3c06n154bl3 70 4 hum4n r34d3r. If you ban "test", the user will do "t_e_s_t". Ban that, and the user will do "t.e.s.t" or "t__e__s__t". Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the [`\b` delimiter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary) - as in `/\bc*m|\bc*m\b|c*m\b/`.  This is as good as you can get with regular expressions.  As MikeC said, Natural language processing is a huge field.

**Postscript:** on closer inspection `_` is actually a word character, so in order for the `\b` approach to work, you'd need to replace `'_'` with `' '`.

Comment: This is helpful, but it's likely in a username for words to not have spaces between them.

Comment: @4castle spaces are not allowed at all. They are stopped onkeydown. Would this still help me?

Comment: *"They are stopped onkeydown"* - So in other words they're not stopped, because the user could edit the field using drag'n'drop or by pasting spaces via the *Edit* menu.

Comment: @AngelPolitis It could help just a little. It would only work if the word started and ended with a non-word character. It doesn't necessarily have to be a space, it could be any punctuation or number.

Comment: @nnnnnn they get filtered out on blur, if in case someone does so.

Comment: @4castle so, would `a_big_c*mshot` be banned this way?

Comment: @AngelPolitis No, sadly underscores are counted as word characters and not punctuation. And I was wrong earlier, numbers are also word characters. A word character is `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, and `_`.

Comment: I accept this answer since it's the most helpful I got.